# Android Studio - Passing a title and description through ListView

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I have created an activity which I need to update with posts made up of a "title" and "description". Earlier a ListView was suggested as an option but I do not know how to add two pieces of text (title and description) to each individual item of the ListView through a String array.

There is a "new post" button on the feed interface that opens a new activity containing 2 TextEdit boxes for adding the title and description.

When "post" is pressed on this second activity I am trying to move the title and description into an array that updates the ListView on the first activity with a new item containing the title and description stated within the TextEdit boxes.

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated,

Aaron.

Comment: I had a friend back in the day named Aaron Bell aka 'Taco'... That's not you, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best possible way to this is by using a data base. Android has a built in SQLite data base. You can store in all your data into the data base and query it to get a key/value pair array, which you can pass to your listView adapter class and get the data you need into the list view.
Hope this link helps you out-

androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-populate-listview-from-sqlite.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you Shivam - led me in the right direction I believe!